# Priority between custom and built-in directve

Tags: angularjs, scope, directive

I am reading *ng-book-r27*.

There are some something i can't understand well.

About 'Scope Option' of The chapter 'Directives Explained'.

First confusion:

> If multiple directives on an element provide an isolate scope, only
>   one new scope is applied. Root elements within the template of a
>   directive always get a new scope; thus, for those objects, scope is
>   set to true by default.

I think that mean other directives will use the isolate scope as theirs.
is that right?

Second confusion:

[example of inherited scope](http://jsbin.com/ITEBAF/1/edit?html,output)

ng-init has higher priority than custom directive.
Why the expression of ng-init will use the scope of custom dirctive.

I find a recommendation from offical doc about ng-init:

> This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into
>   your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such
>   as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo
>   below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these
>   few cases, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize
>   values on a scope.

OK, I can ignore the strange behavior of second confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not read the book `ng-book`, but as far as I know, the statement of your first confusion does not conform with the **[AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)** regarding inherited and isolated scopes within a directive.

The statement above is simply not possible, having multiple directives that each have their own `isolated` scope would produce a **[$compile:multidir](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir)** error. Here is a **[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/KKP9vSa3aVVuYRXlsXQK?p=preview)**.

```
.directive('elem1', function($rootScope) {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {}
  };

})

.directive('elem2', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {}
  }
});
```

---

After scanning the AngularJS documentation, there is no supporting statement that validates the statement:

> If multiple directives on an element provide an isolate scope, only
>   one new scope is applied.

The closest statement I see that is similar to the statement above is the `scope: true` option definition when creating directives:

> true: A new child scope that **prototypically inherits** from its parent
>   will be created for the directive's element. If multiple directives on
>   the same element request a new scope, only one new scope is created.
>   The new scope rule does not apply for the root of the template since
>   the root of the template always gets a new scope.

The statement above suggests that when multiple directives with `scope: true` option (not an isolated scope) resides in a single element, it would create one scope and everything else is a shared scope. **[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/HNTBzNNRZXhUMldNGFo2?p=preview)**

```
.directive('elem1', function($rootScope) {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope) {
      console.log(scope.hello);
    }
  };

})

.directive('elem2', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.hello = 'world';
      console.log(scope.hello);
    }
  }
});
```

You would notice that both directives logs `'world'`, this obviously supports the statement above.

---

If you read more in the **[`$compile scope` AngularJS documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)**, you would see that:

> In general it's possible to apply more than one directive to one
>   element, but there might be limitations depending on the type of scope
>   required by the directives. The following points will help explain
>   these limitations. For simplicity only two directives are taken into
>   account, but it is also applicable for several directives:
>
> **no scope + no scope** => Two directives which don't require their own scope will use their parent's scope
>
> **child scope + no scope** => Both directives will share one single child scope
>
> **child scope + child scope** => Both directives will share one single child scope
>
> **isolated scope + no scope** => The isolated directive will use it's own created isolated scope. The other directive will use its parent's scope
>
> **isolated scope + child scope** => **Won't work!** Only one scope can be related to one element. Therefore these directives cannot be applied to the same element.
>
> **isolated scope + isolated scope** => Won't work! Only one scope can be related to one element. Therefore these directives cannot be applied to the same element.

Perhaps you're having problems identifying the difference between prototypically inherted scopes and isolated scopes. You might want to read the **[`$rootScope.Scope $new()`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$new)** method, the `isolate` parameter definition.

First question:

> I think that mean other directives will use the isolate scope as
>   theirs. is that right?

The answer is an absolute no, in reference towards multiple directives with isolated scope, it would produce the `$copile:multidir` error.

For your second question:

> ng-init has higher priority than custom directive. Why the expression
>   of ng-init will use the scope of custom directive?

As for directives that do not have isolated scopes or directives that don't prototypically inherit from their parent scope, you can directly associate those directives as having a `scope` property definition with a falsey scope value:

> falsy: No scope will be created for the directive. The directive will
>   use its parent's scope

If a directive is bound to an element with a scope of its own then it simply uses the scope of that element, otherwise it seeks all the scope instances within the scope chain until it reaches the `$rootScope`.

Comment: not clear about sentence below:

''As a trait for all directives that does create their own isolated scope nor protoypically inherit from a parent scope, you can directly refer to the scope property definition for a falsey scope value:

falsy: No scope will be created for the directive. The directive will use its parent's scope.''

U mean neither create nor inherit ,right?
   still confusing words bellow:
''If a directive is bound to an element with a scope of its own then it simply uses the scope of that element.''

Comment: I'm sorry that is supposed to be "does not create", let me edit that, good catch! I rephrased it :)

Comment: 'If a directive is bound to an element with a scope of its own then it simply uses the scope of that element.'
I think you mean a directve is bound to an element who has a scope. sorry i am not a native english speaker if this upset you

Comment: What I meant and what you meant are technically the same :)